# Cross-Platform Mobile Development For Nokia and Android

Tags: android, mobile, cross-platform, nokia

Good morning all :)

Guys, here in my company, told me to develop a mobile application that must be runnable in Nokia and Android Platform.

I already developed an android application, and really, i don't understand how is possible that we can have another layer of indirection between these 2 platforms.
I know that both run in java, but the programming model is so different.

I already searched, and i found for android and iphone, but my really question is, if is possible for Android and Nokia one programming way to build the same aplication with the same behaviour?

Comment: when you mention Nokia, is it about Windows Phone or Symbian ?

Comment: Nokia release devices with Windows Mobile OS, Symbian, QT, etc.. let me know OS Name or device name

Comment: I was searching for Symbian. Do you guys know something? I am starting to think that i need develop each one application for each one platform.

Comment: I decided to install phoneGap, and i developed an "Hello World" application. My question is, and i think is the more obvious, i need to create a new template for each platform and use the same code (html, javascript and css) in each platform? Or i have one way to build the android aplication to all other platforms? Can you explain me this. Thanks